# .NET Core, Windows Nano Server and System.Management.Automation

Tags: .net, windows, powershell

The Nano is a server operating system optimized for cloud. It does not have local user interface, nor does it even support local log-on. According to given information regarding Windows Nano Server, it does not contain full .NET Framework, but .NET Core. This makes sense so far.

.NET libraries contained in the Core are listed [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx-progress/blob/master/src-diff/README.md). Some are complete, some are not. But what I don't understand is that System.Management.Automation is missing from the list entirely.

This library is the one used to use PowerShell cmdlets in .NET applications. Considering how important PowerShell is today for sysadmins in particular, this omission in light of the Nano Server seems simply weird.

So does this mean functionality provided by System.Management.Automation is not available in Windows Nano Server?

Comment: It seems that the thing can be remote managed through PowerShell: http://www.cio.com/article/2945512/windows/is-windows-nano-server-a-data-center-game-changer.html

Comment: Indeed it can, but that's not the same thing as being able to run PowerShell cmdlets in.NET applications.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use the latest powershell release for .NET core - https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases

Reference the dll from the downloaded package and you should be able to run the powershell command.